# How to override value specified in build.properties during java execution

Tags: java, ant, ups

I have property values set in build.properties file which are being used by the java code. (This is part of UPS Quantum View)
    `build.properties file
    url=https://onlinetools.ups.com/ups.app/xml/QVEvents
    accesskey=XYZ
    username=QWER
    password=12345
    subsname=OUTBOUNDFULL`

build.properties is referenced in the build.xml

```
<property file="build.properties"/>
```

I want to use different values of subsname at different times. so I was trying

`ant -Dsubsname=OUTBOUND_EST`  from the command line but in the build it keeps taking value from the build.properties file as OUTBOUNDFULL. 
Is there any other way to do this.

(Note: This is part of UPS Quantum view)
Part of java code where the values are used

```
public class JAXBQVClient {
private static final String LICENSE_NUMBER = "accesskey";
private static final String USER_NAME = "username";
private static final String SUBSNAME = "subsname";
private static final String PASSWORD = "password";
private static final String ENDPOINT_URL="url";
private static final String OUT_FILE_LOCATION = "out_file_location";
static Properties props = null;

static{
    props = new Properties();
    try{
        props.load(new FileInputStream("./build.properties"));
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
}
```

Comment: When do you want to override properties'values during ant build or when your java code is executed?

Comment: @P.A.Cros I want to override it when the java code is being executed. That is the time when it takes the parameters from the build.properties file like acceskey, username, password and subsname to form a Request xml.

Comment: @P.A.Cros - Is there any way to override the values of build.properties during java execution.

Comment: Sorry, I was out of office for a few days... I just post an answer that could solve your problem (I hope so...)

Answer (score 0):

Since your `build.properties` file is read by a java process that is launch by your ant build (I guess), you may use [filterset](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterset.html) ant concept.

For instance, you may define a properties file template `build-template.properties` like this:

```
url=https://onlinetools.ups.com/ups.app/xml/QVEvents
accesskey=XYZ
username=QWER
password=12345
subsname=@SUBNAMEKEY@
```

and then use a filterset when copying it into the `build.properties` you are using for a specific run:

```
<copy file="build-template.properties" toFile="build.properties">
  <filterset>
    <filter token="SUBNAMEKEY" value="${SUBNAMEVALUE}"/>
  </filterset>
</copy>
```

then calling `ant -DSUBNAMEVALUE=OUTBOUND_EST` should generate a `build.properties` file with `subsname=OUTBOUND_EST`

Comment: @P.A.Cros.Thank you for your response. I added this: <project name="Sample Tool" basedir="." default="run">
 `<property file="build.properties" />
 <copy file="build-template.properties" toFile="build.properties">
   <filterset>
     <filter token="SUBNAMEKEY" value="${SUBNAMEVALUE}"/>
   </filterset>
 </copy>`
 to the build.xml and the build.properties and build-template.properties. But it still takes the value set in original build.properties. Any changes to be made in build.xml according to you?

Comment: @Max It is important to place `property file="build.properties"` call after you copy with substitution your template file. task `property file="build.properties"` will load and set any properties in the file, and when it is done, value for each properties can no longer be overriden